# Alinear/Centrar Calendar Chart Google

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chart-api

Tengo una web en la que quiero mostrar unos gráficos, pero no consigo centrar el Calendar Chart de ninguna forma. Simplemente no hace caso a nada. Los mapas no han dado ningún problema, pero el Calendar no consigo centrarlo de ninguna forma. A ver si alguno me puede echar un cable.

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300, 400, 500, 700';

body {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

header{
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  align-content: center;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
}

header img{
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  transition-duration: .2s;
}

header img:hover{
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

header h1{
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

.mapas{
  width: 100%;
  height: 720px;
  display: flex;
}

.mapas div{
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.f{
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<html>

 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="icon" href="resources/werulepeque.png">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/maps.css">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
 </head>

 <header>
  <img class="cabecera" src="resources/werulegrande.png">
  <h1>Estadísticas generales</h1>
 </header>
 
 <body>
  <div class="mapas">
   <div>
    <h1>Nota media</h1>
    <div id="mapa1"></div>
   </div>
   <div>
    <h1>Ratio tests por persona y día</h1>
    <div id="mapa2"></div>
   </div>
   <div>
    <h1>Cantidad de usuarios</h1>
    <div id="mapa3"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="franjasmes">
  </div>
 </body>
 <script>
  google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages':['geochart'],
  // Note: you will need to get a mapsApiKey for your project.
  // See: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#load-settings
  'mapsApiKey': 'AIzaSyCBvatIme596a7vSTsiu6h9jakhY5gLnuY'
  });
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

  function drawRegionsMap() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
   ['Country', 'Nota media'],
   ['ES-CL', 90],
   ['ES-MD', 85],
   ['ES-MC', 70],
   ['ES-CT', 92],
   ]);

   var options = {
   'title':'Map',
   'width': 480,
   'height': 480,
   region: 'ES',
   'resolution':'provinces',
   colorAxis: {minValue:60, maxValue:100, colors: ['white','#00bfff','lightgreen']},
   backgroundColor: 'white',
   datalessRegionColor: 'white',
   defaultColor: '#f5f5f5',


   };

   var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('mapa1'));

   chart.draw(data, options);
           
  }
 </script>
<script>
  google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages':['geochart'],
  // Note: you will need to get a mapsApiKey for your project.
  // See: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#load-settings
  'mapsApiKey': 'AIzaSyCBvatIme596a7vSTsiu6h9jakhY5gLnuY'
  });
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

  function drawRegionsMap() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
   ['Country', 'Tests por persona y día'],
   ['ES-CL', 1],
   ['ES-MD', 3],
   ['ES-EX', 4],
   ['ES-GA', 2],
   ]);

   var options = {
   'title':'Map',
   'width': 480,
   'height': 480,
   region: 'ES',
   'resolution':'provinces',
   colorAxis: {colors: ['lightgreen', 'green']},
   backgroundColor: 'white',
   datalessRegionColor: 'white',
   defaultColor: '#f5f5f5',


   };

   var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('mapa2'));

   chart.draw(data, options);
           
  }
 </script>
<script>
  google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages':['geochart'],
  // Note: you will need to get a mapsApiKey for your project.
  // See: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#load-settings
  'mapsApiKey': 'AIzaSyCBvatIme596a7vSTsiu6h9jakhY5gLnuY'
  });
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

  function drawRegionsMap() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
   ['Country', 'Popularity'],
   ['ES-CL', 200],
   ['ES-MD', 300],
   ['ES-MC', 100],
   ['ES-CT', 500],
   ]);

   var options = {
   'title':'Map',
   'width': 480,
   'height': 480,
   region: 'ES',
   'resolution':'provinces',
   colorAxis: {colors: ['lightyellow', 'yellow']},
   backgroundColor: 'white',
   datalessRegionColor: 'white',
   defaultColor: '#f5f5f5',


   };

   var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('mapa3'));

   chart.draw(data, options);
           
  }
 </script>
 <script>
  google.charts.load("current", {packages:["calendar"]});
       google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

     function drawChart() {
         var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
         dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Date' });
         dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'number', id: 'Número de test' });
         dataTable.addRows([
          [ new Date(2018, 2, 4), 20 ],
          [ new Date(2018, 2, 5), 15 ],
          [ new Date(2018, 2, 12), 5 ],
          [ new Date(2018, 2, 13), 1 ],
          [ new Date(2018, 2, 19), 0 ],
          [ new Date(2018, 2, 23), 10 ],
          [ new Date(2018, 2, 24), 12 ],
          [ new Date(2018, 2, 30), 20 ]
      ]);

         var chart = new google.visualization.Calendar(document.getElementById('franjasmes'));

         var options = {
           title: "Distribución del trabajo durante el mes",
         };

         chart.draw(dataTable, options);
     }
 </script>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

No vas a poder centrarlo, tienes que ponerlo en un contenedor base y centrar el contenedor que te menciono yo lo centro con bootstrap 4 tiene la opcion de centrar 6 columnas asi que la grafica la le doy width 100%  y height del que quiero usualmente es de 600px, asi la grafica se centra y de paso se hace responsive.

Comment: Para que se entienda mejor la respuesta pon un ejemplo con código